# How to integrate findbugs with maven

Tags: maven-2, findbugs

Please provide steps to integrate findbugs with maven

Answer (score 4):

Use the Maven Findbugs plugin. See the [usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) of the plugin for examples.

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs looks for bugs in Java programs. It is based on the concept of bug patterns in order to integrate with Maven, put the following in your plugins section.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <!– Optional directory to put FindBugs xdoc xml report –>
        <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
        <threshold>High</threshold>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```